# ERROR: failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buil dkit-mount998491540/Dockerfile: no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker

I'm trying to build a simple react app and dockerize it using yarn, pnpm, npm and gulp.

My folder structure is:

```
build/
docker-compose.yml package.json    
src/ 
componants/               
dockerfile          
pages/          
tsconfig.json compose.yaml gulpfile.js pnpm-lock.yaml  yarn.lock docker-compose.debug.yml  
node_modules/      
public/
```

My package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "dylansteeletech",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.7.13",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-markdown": "^8.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.14.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.4.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^4.0.2"
  }
}
```

I've tried building my docker container using `docker built -t dylansteeletech .`:

```
$ docker build -t dylansteeletech .
[+] Building 0.5s (2/2) FINISHED                                 docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                       0.3s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2B                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                          0.2s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                            0.0s
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buil
dkit-mount998491540/Dockerfile: no such file or directory

View build details: docker-desktop://dashboard/build/default/default/fr6ylromwvv
4me4vkxmqmgg01
```

I don't understand what I did wrong, usually that command works well. I'm not sure, is it because I added pnpm and yarn? I noticed this error so then I edited my dockerfile to npm instead of pnpm

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

# Comments are provided throughout this file to help you get started.
# If you need more help, visit the Dockerfile reference guide at
# https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

ARG NODE_VERSION=18.16.1
ARG PNPM_VERSION=8.6.6

################################################################################
# Use node image for base image for all stages.
FROM node:${NODE_VERSION}-alpine as base

# Set working directory for all build stages.
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install pnpm.
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.npm \
    npm install -g pnpm@${PNPM_VERSION}

################################################################################
# Create a stage for installing production dependecies.
FROM base as deps

# Download dependencies as a separate step to take advantage of Docker's caching.
# Leverage a cache mount to /root/.local/share/pnpm/store to speed up subsequent builds.
# Leverage bind mounts to package.json and pnpm-lock.yaml to avoid having to copy them
# into this layer.
RUN --mount=type=bind,source=package.json,target=package.json \
    --mount=type=bind,source=pnpm-lock.yaml,target=pnpm-lock.yaml \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.local/share/pnpm/store \
    npm install --prod --frozen-lockfile

################################################################################
# Create a stage for building the application.
FROM deps as build

# Download additional development dependencies before building, as some projects require
# "devDependencies" to be installed to build. If you don't need this, remove this step.
RUN --mount=type=bind,source=package.json,target=package.json \
    --mount=type=bind,source=pnpm-lock.yaml,target=pnpm-lock.yaml \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.local/share/pnpm/store \
    npm install --frozen-lockfile

# Copy the rest of the source files into the image.
COPY . .
# Run the build script.
RUN npm run build

################################################################################
# Create a new stage to run the application with minimal runtime dependencies
# where the necessary files are copied from the build stage.
FROM base as final

# Use production node environment by default.
ENV NODE_ENV production

# Run the application as a non-root user.
USER node

# Copy package.json so that package manager commands can be used.
COPY package.json .

# Copy the production dependencies from the deps stage and also
# the built application from the build stage into the image.
COPY --from=deps /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/build ./build


# Expose the port that the application listens on.
EXPOSE 3000

# Run the application.
CMD npm start
```

Comment: The last argument to `docker build` is the current directory `.`, and the error message says the `Dockerfile` isn't there.  Do you need to rename it to have a capital `D`?

Comment: with it work if i use docker build -t Dylansteeletech . and change my directary name to match the command?

Comment: No, that changes the name of the image that would be generated.  Docker won't find a file named `dockerfile` with a lowercase `d`.

Comment: will i have any sucess if i change the name to DOCKERFILE instead?

Comment: No, you will not.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command from the directory where the dockerfile is located.

In this case assuming your docerkfile is sample.Dockerfile.

```
docker build -t dylansteeletech - < sample.Dockerfile
```

Answer (score -1):

the Dockerfile might have an invisible .txt extension (shouldnt have any), check it out and rename it in case it has

Comment: Very unlikely. The file listing shows other endings, and has Posix-style directory separators (/), so why/how should the ending be hidden for just this file?